# Unable to connect to FTP server using FileZilla, get response message as ÿý%ÿû

Tags: windows, ftp, filezilla

I am trying to connect to FTP server using FileZilla. I get the following sequence of messages.

```
Status: Resolving address of <myhostname> 
Status: Connecting to <myhostip>:23...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   ÿý%ÿûÿûÿý'ÿýÿý
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

However I am able to connect using FTP protocol in windows explorer. I need to copy a large file, it fails on windows and FileZilla is not working. Can anybody offer me any solution to the reason why I am getting such a garbled message?

Comment: Did you specify port 23?  Is that the port your FTP server is running on?  Typically that is Telnet, not FTP.

Comment: damn! so that is the issue. i must have given 21

Answer (score 2):

Port 21 is FTP in a default configuration, not 23.